# Is it possible to navigate directly to a child card?

Tags: gmail-addons

I have a list of root cards that I'd like to display on the home page of my add-on, but depending on the content of the email I'd like the add-on to open directly into a child card (but then allow the user to hit the back button to return to home).

What I want essentially is to be able to return a set of root cards in my onTriggerFunction, but then conditionally navigate the user to one of these cards

Answer (score 1):

Yes that could be done. Lets say you have root1 `burger`, and root 2 `fries` card. And say both are capable of navigating to the child card using a button `order` where you need to fill out a form.

Now you must have written code to navigate to the `order` from like the following in both root cards.

`var navToOrder = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(leadAddCard);
        return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
        .setNavigation(navToOrder)
        .build();`

To conditionally open the child card use 
`return navToOrder` when your condition is satisfied,
instead of returning the root card in the `onTriggerFunction`.